# jQuery Chosen Plugin on live

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I'm having some trouble finding a way to register a multiselect with the Chosen plugin.
I'm dynamically loading a form into the DOM with Ajax, and want one of the selects to make use of the Chosen plugin.

I've tried calling

```
$('.chosen-element').chosen()
```

on ajaxComplete, which suggests that I won't be able to generate a custom event and bind to it. I've also tried cloning the returned select and registering the cloned element with the plugin, but to no avail.

Has anyone found a nice way to get Chosen working dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You do `not have closing quote` for the selector, you have semi colon `;` instead of single quote `'`

Change

```
$('.chosen-element;).chosen()
```

To

```
$('.chosen-element').chosen()
```

Comment: Woops, sorry that was a massive typo.

Comment: The typo was my bad, the issue is unrelated :)